# PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword returns 406 status code

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use code below to authenticate my mail reading service, but it always returns 406 (Unacceptable).

```
    public class OutlookAuthProvider : IAuthenticationProvider, IOutlookAuthProvider
    {
        private IPublicClientApplication _msalClient;
        private string[] _scopes;
        private SecureString _password;
        private string _username;
        private IAccount _userAccount;
        private string _tenantId;

        public OutlookAuthProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var outlookSection = configuration.GetSection("Outlook");

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (var ch in outlookSection.GetValue<string>("Password"))
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(ch);
            }

            _scopes = outlookSection.GetValue<string>("Scopes").Split(',');
            _password = securePassword;
            _username = outlookSection.GetValue<string>("Username");
            _tenantId = outlookSection.GetValue<string>("TenantId");
            var appId = outlookSection.GetValue<string>("ClientId");

            _msalClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(appId)
                .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount, true)
                //.WithTenantId(_tenantId)
                .Build();
        }

        public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            if (_userAccount == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var result = await _msalClient
                        .AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopes, _username, _password)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    _userAccount = result.Account;
                    return result.AccessToken;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error getting access token: {exception.Message}");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var result = await _msalClient
                    .AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, _userAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                return result.AccessToken;
            }
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetAccessToken());
        }
    }
```

I have tried:

1. Switching to tenant id
2. Enabling feature below, although most guides are already outdated, there it has name **Default Client Type**
   [image]
3. Played with setting different enum values instead of current one `.WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount, true)` , although my manifest clearly says `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`
4. Integration assitant says that everything is ok

[image]

5. Graph Explorer works fine without asking any permissions, but code snippets do not show how to implement `IAuthenticationProvider`

Could you spot the mistake?

Graph API call

```
var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages.Request()
     .Select(x => new
      {
           x.Id
      }).GetAsync();
```

**Update**

Fiddler shows two requests:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/userrealm/myusertest12313@outlook.com?api-version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
x-client-SKU: MSAL.NetCore
x-client-Ver: 4.22.0.0
x-client-OS: Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041
Accept: application/json
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
x-ms-request-id: bc563432-9d8d-45f4-9641-84cfcbcd1300
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.11198.13 - AMS1 ProdSlices
Set-Cookie: fpc=AhoxkrrnUR9IqdbAufwK_RQ; expires=Mon, 30-Nov-2020 06:04:07 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=userrealm.json
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2020 06:04:06 GMT
Content-Length: 363

{"ver":"1.0","account_type":"Federated","domain_name":"live.com","federation_protocol":"WSTrust","federation_metadata_url":"https://nexus.passport.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml","federation_active_auth_url":"https://login.live.com/rst2.srf","cloud_instance_name":"microsoftonline.com","cloud_audience_urn":"urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline"}
```

and second one. Accept application/json, and link returns xml? Hmmm...

```
GET https://nexus.passport.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: nexus.passport.com
x-client-SKU: MSAL.NetCore
x-client-Ver: 4.22.0.0
x-client-OS: Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041
Accept: application/json
```

with response:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
PPServer: PPV: 30 H: BL02PFE37B62997 V: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2020 06:04:07 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Exact steps to reproduce:

1. Create Outlook account
2. Log in to Azure Portal with Outlook credentials
3. Create App registration
4. Fill Outlook login and password, and app registration's client id in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have any tenant created in my AD, so I had to create one first. Then I created App registration under this tenant. Finally I changed ClientId and TenantId values in my application.

Answer (score 0):

[MS Graph 406 status code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors#http-status-codes) signals the service doesn’t support the format requested in the Accept header. The error is not in the authentication process but the request itself.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really helpful for me. Could it be related to account itself? I am using Azure AD without Azure subscription (just logged in to Azure with Outlook account), so I can't grant delegated permissions as an admin. Was able to use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder for another account that has subscription

Comment: @YegorAndrosov nope. Can you share your Graph call code?

Comment: Exception occurs before graph call (in the acquire token method), I don't think it is relevant

Comment: I added graph api call, anyway

Comment: @YegorAndrosov the graph call is fine. Please share the correlation id and timestamp of the AAD failure. If it's not exposed in the exception then use fiddler to trace it.

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla response is empty. I attached fiddler requests. so this is not AAD?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov ROPC does not support personal (non work) accounts.